# Data cleaning - removing special character 95

Tags: excel

I'm trying to clean data in Excel.

The first inquiry, code(D3), returned `32`. I then used the following function to clean it:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D3,CHAR(32),"",1)
```

Then, it still wasn't clean, and both the CLEAN and TRIM functions were not working. So the second inquiry, code(), returned `95`.

However, using this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(D3,CHAR(95),"",1)
```

did not work. And nothing works. The CLEAN and TRIM functions still don't do anything.

How can I get ride of the CHAR 95?

Comment: It's not really clear what the actual outcomes of your tries were, but if you want to remove all instances of a character from a cell's value then you need (eg) `=SUBSTITUTE(D3,CHAR(95),"")` or just `=SUBSTITUTE(D3,"_","")` - don't use the last parameter.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I tried this.... but the outcome is no change. Code(D3) still outputs "95" and there are still spaces before the numbers in the cell.... any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Using a formula like `=SUBSTITUTE(D3,"_","")` won't affect the *value in D3*, so `CODE(D3)` isn't going to change.   The cell containing the substitute formula will contain the "cleaned" value.